# While accessing a list through a "for" loop i.e. "for x in list:" , is there a way to access the "x+1" item in the list in the same loop?

Tags: python, list, loops

While accessing a list through a `for` loop, i.e., `for x in list:`, is there a way to access the `x+1` item in the list in the same loop?

For example,

```
list = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]
```

is there some way to add 1+2, 2+3, 3+4 like

```
for x in list:
    print(x+(x+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can either loop by indices instead of values, and make sure to stop at the next-to-last index to avoid an `IndexError: list index out of range` exception when accessing the next index:

```
l = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]

for i in range(len(l) - 1):
    print(l[i] + l[i + 1])
```

Something more Pythonic, however, would be to `zip` your list with a right-shifted version of itself:

```
l = [1 ,2 ,3 ,4]

for i, j in zip(l, l[1:]):
    print(i + j)
```

*PS*: avoid using built-in type `list` as a variable name.

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one option.

One is to use enumarate()

```
for counter, x in enumerate(a_list):
    print(str(x+a_list[counter+1]))
```

Will throw an IndexError in the last iteration, so you have to handle that case also.